# Sending command using USART

Tags: microcontroller, avr, embedded, programming, usart

I am new to this kind of communication. I am able to send command from PC to AT90USB1287 microcontroller as well as able to get response using USB communication. Now i have connected another microcontroller(ATmega32) to this board via USART communication. I am trying to send command from PC to this board. Both controllers have different commands. So i have created an array containing both controllers commands in AT90USB1287 controller. My concept is compare the incoming command from PC with all commands in array based on result i am trying to send commands to ATmega32 controller using USART. I have the code as shown below.

```
#include <90usb1287.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <interface.h>
#include <uart_drv.h>

#define CMD_SIZE    57 
#define USB_CMD_SIZE    52 

flash unsigned char * flash cmdList[CMD_SIZE] = { 
"",             // [0] no com 
"INFO",          // [1] Displayes version date etc. 
"SET",        // [2] Reset CPU 
"boot",         // [3] Goto boot 
"UMP",         // [4] Display manual debug info 
"AUTO",          // [5] Start automatic scanning 
"STRP",         // [6] Stop scanning 
"STAF",         // [7] Set start frequency 
"STOF",         // [8] Set stop frequency 
"RES",          // [9] Display manual debug info 
"RATES",         // [10] Display manual debug info 
"GAINAD",         // [11] Set gain 
"SCANSD",         // [12] Start custom scan 
"SETUP",        // [13] Display manual scan setup info 
"TEMP",         // [14] Set temperature (Celsius) 
..................... 
......................  
"COM",       // [52] no com 
"PINF",         // [53] Displays version date etc. 
"PSCAN",         // [54] 
"PWGF",          // [55] 
"PADC"          // [56] Clear Flash memmory (stopLog)       
};

unsigned char SerIn[SIBUFSIZE];     // Input buffer (raw data)
unsigned char RxCnt;                // Location of next byte to be written
unsigned char RdCnt;                // Location of next byte to be read
unsigned char BufCnt;               // Size of unread contents in ring buffer
unsigned char CompIndex;            // Index in Copmare array
unsigned char Compare[COMPBUFSIZE]; // Command string tokenizer

 unsigned char Uart_CompIndex;            // Index in Copmare array

 unsigned char Command;              // Current Command is executed
 unsigned int  Param;                // Parameter used in command
   float  Param2;               // Optional (second) parameter used in command
  unsigned long Param3;               // Optional (third) parameter in command

 extern unsigned char Plot;
 unsigned char Step;


 // USART1 Receiver interrupt service routine
 interrupt [USART1_RXC] void usart1_rx_isr(void){   

 char status,data;
 status=UCSR1A;
  data=UDR1;
  printf("%c", data);
 }

 // USB Receive
 void catchString(void){

 while(UEBCLX){

    if(++BufCnt >= SIBUFSIZE){               // Increment & check for buffer overflow  
        BufCnt = SIBUFSIZE-1;                // Set to max value   
        return;                              // Skip char
    }else{                                   // Else: if buffer ok
       if(++RxCnt >= SIBUFSIZE) RxCnt = 0;// Increment read counter, if 10 -> 0 (max 9)
    SerIn[RxCnt] = UEDATX;               // Write to SBUF (load the transmit register)
    }
  }  
  }


 // Read from ringbuffer
 char getcharb(void){

    if(BufCnt){                                 // If anything
    BufCnt--;                               // Decrement buffer counter
    if(++RdCnt >= SIBUFSIZE) RdCnt = 0;   // Increment read counter, if 10 -> 0 (max 9)
    return SerIn[RdCnt];                    // Read from SBUF (access receive register)
 }
 return 0;
 }

void getcom(void){

  unsigned char c;

 // Read from ring-buffer and fill in Compare buffer
  while(BufCnt){                          
        c = getcharb();                    
    if(CompIndex >= COMPBUFSIZE) CompIndex = 0;
        // Analyze char
        if(c == '#'){                     
              CompIndex = 0;
        }else if(c == '\r'){                            
              Compare[CompIndex]='\0';    
              break;                      
        }else if(c == '\n'){              
              // Do nothing (ignore)
        }else if(c == 8){                 
              if(CompIndex) CompIndex--;  

        }else if(c == 9){      // Horizontal TAB 
              help();          // Write out cmds

        }else if(c == 27){        // ESC button
              Command = 0;// Stop current command

              Param = 0;       // Clear argument
              Plot = 0;     // Stop plotting
              Step = 0;
        }else{
              Compare[CompIndex++]=c;     
        }if(!BufCnt) return;                                     
  }CompIndex=0;                           

  c = 1;
  while(c<CMD_SIZE){          // For each command       
        if(strncmpf(Compare,cmdList[c],strlenf(cmdList[c])) == 0) break;
        c++; 
  }   

  if(c> USB_CMD_SIZE){    // this is for ATmega32
      Command = c;
       if(isdigit(Compare[strlenf(cmdList[c])])){
              Param = atoi(&Compare[strlenf(cmdList[c])]);
              c = strpos(Compare,':');                 
              if(c > 0){
                    Param2 = atof(&Compare[c+1]);
                    c = strrpos(Compare,':');
                    if(c > strpos(Compare,':')) Param3 = atol(&Compare[c+1]);
                    else  Param3 = 0; 
              }else{ 
                Param2 = 0;
                Param3 = 0;
              }
        }else{
            Param  = 0;
            Param2 = 0;
            Param3 = 0;
        }              
           uart_putchar(Compare);
    //printf("@%s\r\n",&Compare); //Ack command
      }

  if(c<USB_CMD_SIZE){    //If match on normal cmnd in usb
        Command = c;      
        if(isdigit(Compare[strlenf(cmdList[c])])){
              Param = atoi(&Compare[strlenf(cmdList[c])]);
              c = strpos(Compare,':');                 
              if(c > 0){
                    Param2 = atof(&Compare[c+1]);
                    c = strrpos(Compare,':');
                    if(c > strpos(Compare,':')) Param3 = atol(&Compare[c+1]);
                    else  Param3 = 0; 
              }else{ 
                Param2 = 0;
                Param3 = 0;
              }
        }else{
            Param  = 0;
            Param2 = 0;
            Param3 = 0;
        }
        printf("@%s\r\n",&Compare); //Ack command
  }else{

  if(c>CMD_SIZE-1){             // If match on normal commands

        printf("&E;1;\r\n");  // Command not found
       printf("->Unknown command: 's'\r\n",&Compare); // If no match
        Command = 0;
         Param  = 0;
         Param2 = 0;
         Param3 = 0;
}
  }       
}
```

in the above code i am able to get response from USB controller but not from ATmega32A. I am checking the index is >52(USB_CMD_SIZE)  then send to ATmega32 otherwise send to USB)=1287.

I am getting error in this line

```
uart_putchar(Compare);
```

I have the function for uart_putchar like this.

```
void uart_putchar (char ch)
{
   while(!Uart_tx_ready());
   Uart_set_tx_busy(); // Set Busy flag before sending (always)
   Uart_send_byte(ch);   
   return;
 }
```

even i tried like this

```
  uart_puts(Compare);
```

for that i have written like this

```
  void uart_puts(const char *s)
  {
    while(*s)
      {
         uart_putchar(*s++);
      //    printf("*");
   }    
   }
```

But nothing is working for me. Can anyone help me how to fix this? Do I need any conversion here? If so, please help me with an example.

When i use this code then i am able to get response from atmega32 but what was the problem is this code is sending all commands to both controllers so at that time i have problem so i am trying the above one.

```
 void getcom(void){

  unsigned char c;

  // Read from ring-buffer and fill in Compare buffer
  while(BufCnt){                          // while unread contents in ring-buffer
        c = getcharb();                    // fetch next byte

        if(CompIndex >= COMPBUFSIZE) CompIndex = 0;// overflow protection                    
        // Analyze char
        if(c == '#'){                     // Manual start
              CompIndex = 0;
      uart_putchar(c);
        }else if(c == '\r'){              // CR continue (end of cmd without argument)                         
              Compare[CompIndex]='\0';    // fill in end character of comp string
       uart_putchar(c);
              break;                      // possible valid cmd received -> check out
        }else if(c == '\n'){              // New line (ignore)                         
              // Do nothing (ignore)
        }else if(c == 8){                 // Backspace
              if(CompIndex) CompIndex--;  // decrement index
          uart_putchar(c);
        }else if(c == 9){                 // Horizontal TAB 
              help();                     // Write out cmds
            uart_putchar(c);

        }else if(c == 27){                // ESC button
              Command = 0;                // Stop current command
    uart_putchar(c);

              Param = 0;                  // Clear argument
              Plot = 0;                   // Stop plotting
              Step = 0;
        }else{
              Compare[CompIndex++]=c;     // Default action: Store character

        uart_putchar(c);
        }if(!BufCnt) return;              // if no more data to read -> exit                                          
  }CompIndex=0;                           // reset, ready for next command

  c = 1;


  while(c<CMD_SIZE){          // For each command       
        if(strncmpf(Compare,cmdList[c],strlenf(cmdList[c])) == 0) break;
        c++; 
  }   

  if(c<USB_CMD_SIZE){             // If match on normal commands
        Command = c;      
        if(isdigit(Compare[strlenf(cmdList[c])])){
              Param = atoi(&Compare[strlenf(cmdList[c])]);
              c = strpos(Compare,':');                 
              if(c > 0){
                    Param2 = atof(&Compare[c+1]);
                    c = strrpos(Compare,':');
                    if(c > strpos(Compare,':')) Param3 = atol(&Compare[c+1]);
                    else  Param3 = 0; 
              }else{ 
                Param2 = 0;
                Param3 = 0;
              }
        }else{
            Param  = 0;
            Param2 = 0;
            Param3 = 0;
        }
        printf("@%s\r\n",&Compare); //Ack command
  }else{

  if(c>CMD_SIZE-1){             // If match on normal commands

     //   printf("&E;1;\r\n");  // Command not found
    //    printf("->Unknown command: '%s'\r\n",&Compare); // If no match
        Command = 0;
         Param  = 0;
         Param2 = 0;
         Param3 = 0;
}
  }      
 }
```

this code is sending each and every character to both controllers.

In Compare i have the command like "PSCAN".

```
printf("@%s\r\n",&Compare); //Ack command
```

this line printing like

```
@PSCAN
```

Comment: USB901287  is probably an [AT90USB1287](http://www.atmel.com/Images/7593S.pdf).

Comment: @abdullahkahraman Yes

Comment: How do you define `Compare`, what does it contain? Could you show more code?

Comment: @abdullahkahraman sure, i have updated now have a look at my new updated code.

Comment: I see that `Compare` is not initialized with any values and is only filled when `CompIndex >= COMPBUFSIZE`. Try assigning some dummy values to it, in the initialization, maybe. But I am not sure if this is the problem.

Comment: @abdullahkahraman I tried like that not working. I am thinking its int value and i am trying to put character but i am trying to convert that compare to string, do you have any idea?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea other than removing `const` word from `uart_puts()` function's argument. You should give the error it is giving in the question.

Comment: @abdullahkahraman When i debug i see that in "Compare" I have the command like "PSCAN". you see this line is "printf("@%s\r\n",&Compare); //Ack command"  there it is printing the command. So &Comapare contains the command i am trying to figure out how to send that. Can you have a look at my added explanation to the question.

Comment: I am lost, sorry. I hope someone can help you out with a good answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

Your variable `Compare` is an array of chars. Your `void uart_putchar(char ch)` expects a char, not a char array, so you can't use that one to print `Compare`. Your function `void uart_puts(const char *s)` does expect a char array, but expects it to be constant as well! You might want to try to change that to `void uart_puts(char *s)`.

Also, it's always a good idea to initalize your variable, like this: `unsigned char Compare[COMPBUFSIZE] = {0}` - that way you don't get unexpected results when the program didn't write to the variable yet.

By default, stdout is the UART module. So you can also use the standard `puts` and `putchar` functions to write a string or a character to the UART, like this: `puts(Compare)` or `putchar(Compare[0])`.

If nothing of this works, I'd recommend you to use the `printf` function. The compiler should optimize that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used

```
    fflush()
```

to flush out all the data?The data stays in the buffer unless you do this.I had similar problem.